# UIView process after hidden

Tags: ios, objective-c

I have created the UIView in custom cell using Storyboard and after some process complete I am hiding only UIView through hidden property..

My question is if I scroll again and again by going each cell the UIView will consider for process again and again though uiview is hidden.

I have put uiview in cell (custom cell) and use that uiview to make custom progress bar...So what is best approach: hide or remove .
issue If i remove using removeFrom superview , some uiview progress does not display..

I am hiding uiview in each cell through asynchronous block. Can you post some code how to handle this issue.

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    cutomecell *cell = (customecell*)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"cellid"];
    ......

    [cell.pview setProgress:0];
    [cell.pview setHidden:false];
    [cell.imgContent sd_setImageWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:urlObj[@"img_url"]]
                       placeholderImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"p.png"]
                                options:0
                               progress:^(NSInteger receivedSize, NSInteger expectedSize) {
        CGFloat domandeFloat = receivedSize;
        CGFloat corretteFloat = expectedSize;
        float currentProgress = domandeFloat/corretteFloat;
        [cell.pview setProgress:currentProgress];
    } completed:^(UIImage *image, NSError *error, SDImageCacheType cacheType, NSURL *imageURL) {
        [cell.paintView setHidden:true];                                          
    }];
}
```

Comment: Can you post your code so i can give solution.

Comment: put your code first....!!!!

Comment: if you are catching your cell image than i think above code should work fine. if not than I suggest you to catch cell images.